How to create a PDF file from a Power BI report, for each possible value of a filed (like customer for example)?
I have built a report in Power Bi but some users do not have access to the screen version and need a PDF version by mail.  Their number is too big to do this manually.
To illustrate, I have prepared a simplified version.  This is the semantic model:

So we added a Power Automate flow in the report, that gets triggered by a button.  The manager of the report selects the user id to whom a pdf version must be sent, and the flow prepare the report and sends it.

This works ok.  The pdf version of the report gets exported, but all customers together.  For example, Salesman2 has access to customer id’s 2 and 4, so the PDF reflects the selection of both client ID 2 and 4 together on the same pdf.
How can I create two separate PDF’s?  One with the data for customer id 2 and one for customer ID 4?  In other words, for each selection of the user to whom we send the pdf, how can I run the report for each and every customer id that the user has access to in the RLS table and produce a different PDF file per customer?
I have tried using the filter in the Power Automate pane “Export to File for Power BI Reports” but I don’t manage to have it working: the filter on customer is never working.
If someone can help me here, that would make my day !
Thanks in advance.
